# Cannot use stripe token more than once - Stripe

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect, stripe.js

I'm trying to take charge from customer of connected account,

I have this error `Cannot use stripe token more than once`

This is my code:

```
$customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
  "email" => $customer_email,
  "source" => $token,
),
array("stripe_account" => $stripe_connected_account)
);

$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $the_fix_fee_convert,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "source" => $token,
  "description" => "Charge for subscription"
));
```

I tried to use `customer` instead `source`:

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
  "amount" => $the_fix_fee_convert,
  "currency" => "eur",
  "customer" => $customer->id,
  "description" => "Charge for subscription"
));
```

But Stripe does not find the `customer->id` because its from `$stripe_connected_account`

I also tried this:

```
  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $the_fix_fee_convert,
    "currency" => "eur",
    "customer" => $customer->id,
    "description" => "Charge for subscription"
  ),
  array("stripe_account" => $stripe_connected_account)
  );
```

It works but charge is transfert on the connected account and not on the app account.

Any idea about this?

Comment: The error `Cannot use stripe token more than once` is showing up because you are using a single token to create a Charge and then to create a Customer. If you want to make a charge on the connected account, but get paid on the platform, you must set [an application fee](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#collecting-fees). Can you clarify what you mean by "It works but charge is transfert on the connected account and not on the app account."?

Comment: @henry I want to make a charge on the customer account for the platform and not for the connected account.

Comment: you can't charge the connected account's customers on the platform account. I'd spend some time reading the Connect documentation, especially https://stripe.com/docs/connect/authentication#stripe-account-header

Comment: do you want to charge same customer for connected account  And App account both???

Comment: i think https://stripe.com/docs/connect/shared-customers will helps you